# Why double tap feature is not working in DuckDuckGo browser and Brave browser in IOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, browser, frontend

The below is the code in react.js where I have implemented the feature of double tap. When user double taps on the skill, it removes the tapped skill from skills list and adds it to the teams list and vice-versa.
It is working on every browser in android but it is not working in Duckduckgo browser and brave browser in IOS.
NOTE that it is working in every other browsers in IOS.
""The below code has the functions and variables""

```js
const [team, setTeam] = useState([]);
const [skills, setSkills] = useState([
    { name: 'Acupuncturist' },
    { name: 'Alexander Technique' },
    { name: 'AromaDome Therapy' },
    { name: 'Aromatherapist' },
    { name: 'Body Code' },
    { name: 'Pro Skill' }
]);
// for double tap
const [lastTapTime, setLastTapTime] = useState(0);
const [lastTappedIndex, setLastTappedIndex] = useState(-1);
const handleSkillTouch = (index, isTeamSkill) => {
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    const timeSinceLastTap = now - lastTapTime;

    if (timeSinceLastTap < 300 && index === lastTappedIndex) {
        // Double tap detected
        if (isTeamSkill) {
            const selectedSkill = team[index];
            const newTeam = team.filter((_, i) => i !== index);

            setTeam(newTeam);
            setSkills([...skills, selectedSkill]);
        } else {
            const selectedSkill = skills[index];
            const newSkills = skills.filter((_, i) => i !== index);

            setSkills(newSkills);
            setTeam([...team, selectedSkill]);
        }
    }

    setLastTapTime(now);
    setLastTappedIndex(index);
};
```

""The below is the returned code""

```
<div className="to_flex">
    <div className="button_list_scrollable " style={{ backgroundColor: '#f6faf3' }}>
        {skills.map((skill, index) => (
            <div className="w-embed" key={index} onTouchStart={() => handleSkillTouch(index, false)}>
                <a className="button small-tag tag-shape">
                    <i className="fas fa-circle"></i> {skill.name}
                </a>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>

    <div className="button_list_scrollable" style={{ backgroundColor: '#f6faf3', border: team.length > 0 ? '#8a68a3 2px solid' : '' }}>
        <div className="drag-drop_text my-2" style={{ display: 'block' }}>
            Double tap skills to add
        </div>
        {team.map((skill, index) => (
            <div className="w-embed" key={index} onTouchStart={() => handleSkillTouch(index, true)}>
                <a className="button small-tag tag-shape">
                    <i className="fas fa-circle"></i> {skill.name}
                </a>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried another double tap codes but they are also not working.